# Linq equivalent of aggregate function on multiple tables in one database trip

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, t-sql

I have a table function which returns table names and number of entries within that table :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufnGetLookups] ()
RETURNS
@lookupsWithItemCounts TABLE 
(
    [Name] VARCHAR(100),
    [EntryCount] INT
)

AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @lookupsWithItemCounts([Name],[EntryCount])
     VALUES
               ('Table1', (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1)),
               ('Table2', (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2)),
               ('Table3', (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table))

    RETURN;
END
```

What would be the Linq equivalent of above simple function? Notice that I want to get the result in one single shot and the speed of the operation is quite important for me. If I realise that the converted linq to sql results in a massive bulky sql with performance hit, I would rather stick to my existing user defined function and forget about the linq equivilant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a UNION query.  EG

```
var q = db.Books.GroupBy(g => "Books").Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, EntryCount = g.Count() })
          .Union(db.Authors.GroupBy(g => "Authors").Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, EntryCount = g.Count() }));

var r = q.ToList();
```

Comment: In your statement, when there are no books, it will not appear in the final list. How would you change your linq statement to return 0 rather than empty row when the number of items in a particular table [Books for instance] is zero?

Comment: I don't know of a reasonable way to do that in the LINQ query, so I would just add items to the list.

Answer (score 1):

Not an EF guy, and not sure if this would be more performant.

```
Select TableName = o.name
      ,RowCnt    = sum(p.Rows)
  From sys.objects    as o
  Join sys.partitions as p on o.object_id = p.object_id
 Where o.type = 'U'
   and o.is_ms_shipped = 0x0
   and index_id < 2  -- 0:Heap, 1:Clustered
   --and o.name in ('Table1','Table2','Table3' )   -- Include (or not) your own filter
Group By o.schema_id,o.name
```

**Note:**  Wish I could recall the source of this, but I've used it in my discovery process.

Comment: One question: In what context do you run above linq statement? If you are going for something as hardcore as above statement, why do you even bother to write it in linq rather than running native sql statement using good old SqlCommand?

Comment: @MHOOS I wouldn't write it in linq.  I like keeping code as close to the database as possible.  This means few touch points and/or points of failure.